# Zend table row abstract model method thows Unrecognized method 'updateFromArray()'

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have very specific problem with my Zend Framework application. I use my own Model class called My_Model which is singleton and I use it for calling DB models. Every model extends My_Db_Table class and has a row class that extends My_Db_Table_Row. When I call the model it is OK but the model seems to ignore row class model. Could anybody advise me what am I doing wrong?

The custom class:

```
class My_Model {

protected static $_instance = null;

protected $_services = array();    

private function __construct() {        

}



/**

 * Service classed is called by it's name

 *

 * @param string $name

 * @return My_Db_Table

 */

public function getService($name) {

    if (!isset($this->_services[$name])) {

        $service = new $name();  

        if (!$service instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {

            $type = gettype($service);

            if ($type == 'object') {

                $type = get_class($service);
            }

            throw new Zend_Db_Table_Row_Exception("Class must be a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, but it is $type");

        }

        $this->_services[$name] = $service;

    }

    return $this->_services[$name];

}


}
```

The Zend_Db_Table classes are:

```
<?php

/**

 * This class represents a DB table

 *

 */

class My_Db_Table extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {



/**

 * Fetches the table row by primary key

 *

 * @param string $id

 * @return Product

 */

public function getById($id) {

    return $this->find($id)->current(); 

}
```

}

Row class:

```
<?php

/**

 * Row class

 *

 */

class My_Db_Table_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {

/**

 * Inflector to get the attribute name

 * camelCase -> under_score

 *

 * @param string $columnName

 * @return string

 */

protected function _transformColumn($columnName) {

    $inflector = new Zend_Filter_Inflector ( ":string" );

    $inflector->setRules ( array (

    ':string' => array ('Word_CamelCaseToUnderscore', 'StringToLower' ) ) )

    ;

    $columnName = $inflector->filter ( array ('string' => $columnName ) );

    return $columnName;

}

/**

 * Magic method hook to catch getters and setters

 *

 * @param string $method

 * @param array $args

 */

public function __call($method, array $args) {

    $matches = array ();

    if (preg_match ( '/^get(\w+?)$/', $method, $matches )) {

        $attribute = $matches [1];

        return $this->{$attribute};

    }

    if (preg_match ( '/^set(\w+?)$/', $method, $matches )) {

        $attribute = $matches [1];

        $this->{$attribute} = (count ( $args ) == 1) ? $args [0] : null;

        return;

    }

    return parent::__call ( $method, $args );

}

}
```

To use these classe I use following code:

```
$record = My_Model::getInstance ()->getService ( 'Users' )->getById ( 1 );
$record->updateFromArray(array('auth_token' => 'asfsgfgswg'));
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Message: Unrecognized method 'updateFromArray()'
Stack trace:

#0 /home/www/fbdrives/application/modules/facebook/controllers/IndexController.php(34): Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->__call('updateFromArray', Array)
#1 /home/www/fbdrives/application/modules/facebook/controllers/IndexController.php(34): Zend_Db_Table_Row->updateFromArray(Array)
#2 /home/www/fbdrives/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): Facebook_IndexController->indexAction()
#3 /home/www/fbdrives/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#4 /home/www/fbdrives/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#5 /home/www/fbdrives/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/www/fbdrives/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#7 /home/www/fbdrives/public/index.php(27): Zend_Application->run()
#8 {main}
```

The Users class:

```
 <?php

/**
 * User table model class
 *
 */
class Users extends My_Db_Table {

    /**
     * The DB table name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_name = 'user';

    /**
     * The row class name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_rowclass = 'User';

}
```

The User class that is not called with updateFromArray method:

```
<?php

/**
 * The user model class
 *
 */
class User extends My_Db_Table_Row {


    /**
     * Update values by array values
     *
     * @param array $values
     */
    public function updateFromArray(array $values) {
        $this->setFromArray($values);
        $this->save();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I will provide any necessary info if needed. I am really stucked on this one for a few days now and nothing seems to help. The method updateFromArray is in the User class but the class is not loaded properly.

Thanks in advance for every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be that you are using $_rowclass and not $_rowClass (with an uppercase C).

If you put this line instead, it may work:

```
protected $_rowClass = 'User';
```

That's why in the stack trace you can see Zend_Db_Table being called, which is the default class for a a row that hasn't been set to use a custom class.

Comment: You absolutely ROCK!!! Thank you very much. Took me ages to play with this. It's a bit complex soution of which I am not author and after these horible days I was nearly blind and missed that one! Thanks again. +1 for you :-)